# app domain behavior for .net components accessed through COM interop

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, com-interop, appdomain

I have searched the site for a similar question but did not find anything close.  My apologies to the community if i missed it.

Setup:

- Windows 2008, 64 bit server
- Classic ASP applications (a few of them) deployed in the same application pool under IIS
- Some pages in these classic ASP applications create and access .Net components exposed as COM components.

What we are seeing (we verified this by logging information about the current process and app domain from the .net components exposed through COM):

The .Net components exposed through COM interop are being loaded in a single app domain under the worker process created by IIS for the app pool regardless of which classic asp application under the app pool calls them.  Basically, it is behaving as if IIS is creating a single app domain for COM interop components that is shared by all apps in that app pool. (by "shared" i mean that calls to these .Net components are all routed to that single app domain by IIS regardless of which web app under the app pool is initiating the call).  I was expecting IIS to load the COM interop components in each web app's app domain.

[If we deploy the classic ASP apps in different app pools under IIS, then (obviously) the .Net components are loaded in an app domain within each worker process spun by IIS for each app pool.]

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior and whether it is a known behavior with IIS 7.x and .Net COM components.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour.   When an external COM Client instantiates a COM Visible .NET component that .NET component is loaded into the Default AppDomian for that process.  If a Default AppDomain does not exist then it is created.

Whilst in IIS7 running with an integrated pipeline it would be possible to change this behaviour it would break existing ASP websites that might be migrated to IIS7 that depend (even if that be inadvertently) on this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, makes sense.  I can see now that it would be hard to have it implemented differently:  how would .Net decide what appdomain to load these components in since the only context it has at this point is the calling process.  Thanks again.